# geom_points with different shapes for different dataframes - ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c("ID1","ID1","ID1","ID1","ID2","ID2","ID2","ID2"), col=c("red","red","red","red","green","green","green","green"), x=c("A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D"), y=c(1,2,5,2,3,1,5,6))
df2 <- data.frame(id=c("ID999"), x=c("A","B","C","D"), y=c(2,3,4,2))
```

How can I include both `df1` and `df2` in the same plot, but using a different shape for `df2`?

```
p <- ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y,color=id), data=df1)
p + geom_point() + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y,color=id), shape='#', color="black", size=8, data=df2)
```

the legend label for `ID999` disappears.

Comment: If your main issue is that the legend disappears, it may be enough to specify `show.legend = TRUE` in one or both of your `geom_point()` calls

Answer (score 0):

The tidiest way in my opinion is to join the tables into one, with shape specified in a column:

```
# specify a colour for df2
df2$col <- "blue"

# put the shapes as a column
df1$shape <- "df1"
df2$shape <- "df2"

# bind the 2 tables together and plot
rbind(df1, df2) |>
    ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y,color=id)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape=shape), size = 8) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(df1 = "#", df2 = "*"))
```

Which gives:

[image]